# Display UIPopover just under selected section

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a     UIButton in each section, i want to display a         UIPopover each time when user taps on the         UIButton. Im able to display the popover, but the problem is, the popover is displayed only on first section, even if i tap on some other section in the             UITableView. Below is the code i have written to display the popover.

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:headerBtn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us some code to see what have you tried so that it becomes more clear for us as to what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: @John Doe - sorry...i have edited the question. headerBtn is the Button i have placed in the section of the tableview. Thanks

Comment: change the last line of the code ie [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:headerBtn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];...... replace inView: parameter to inView:self.tableView.. waiting for your reply

Comment: @JohnDoe sorry its behaving the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its expected, you need to maintain the reference of `headerbtn` as unique by using `tag` property for every `section` ;

Try something similar :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // ....
  headerbtn.tag = indexPath.section+25;

}
```

**Action for headerbtn**

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:btn.tag - 25];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIP];

// Use the cell reference to point out the popOver 

// ...........

 [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[cell convertRect:btn.frame toView:self.view] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you be little more specific on // Use the cell reference to point out the popOver. Thanks.

Comment: Check the last line, **presentPopoverFromRect:[cell convertRect:btn.frame toView:self.view]**

Comment: sorry, it appears to display the popover at the top left of the view, all the time.

Comment: check the cell frame at **action For headerBtn**

Comment: let me know, how you'r approaching ?